# maven how to create seperatly ui and backend modules of project

Tags: javascript, java, maven, intellij-idea, multi-module

I tried to apply http://justincalleja.com/2016/04/17/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/ this example but I have a problem. I applied every steps but mu project structure not like this example. I investigate this sample structre on github. This guys project structure like this:

```
-parent
   _pom.xml

 -ui
   -pom.xml
   -src files...

 -backend
    -pom.xml
    -src files...
```

But my project structure like this:

```
-parent
   _pom.xml
   _src files
   _ui
     -pom.xml
     -src files...
   _backend
      -pom.xml
      -src files...
```

If I should explain via words, this example project modules was created as seperatly from parent directory and parent has no java src files please check the sample on github but when I tried parent has src files and modules was created under the parent directory and I failed to create ui module, my ui module is not uu module it is java module.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's not clear what's your concrete problem. Could you be more specific please? And probably you could copy here your pom.xml files?

Comment: @VasiliyVlasov Sorry, I ask via smart phone.

Comment: Thanks to @German editted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want link a parent pom with relative path. You can do this with.

```
- parent
-- pom.xml
- ui
-- pom.xml
- backend
-- pom.xml
```

The pom of children should be this way:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Parent pom

```
<modules>
  <module>../ui</module>
  <module>../be</module>
</modules>
```

If you project has this scaffolding:

```
- parent
-- pom.xml
-- ui
--- pom.xml
-- backend
--- pom.xml
```

The pom should be this way:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
</parent>
```

Parent pom

```
<modules>
  <module>fe</module>
  <module>be</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Project not created like this. Let me try to explain. I try to create parent via Intellij New Project Create wizard. And I suceed it but it include src files(java files) And I created ui and backend modules bu it doesn't be like I want and sample on the link. Because on the linke parent,backend,ui different directories but my backend and ui modules under the parent directory and ui module is not ui module it is like java module. Sorry I share wrong link I editted the link on the entry.

Comment: How did you add backend and ui modules? Did you click "File -> New Module"?

Comment: You probably have bad reference of the sub modules ... there edit the answer so you can see it too. And I try to explain bought models to understand how to change you project.